# How can I get a user control property through the client?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, .net-3.5, user-controls

I am creating a few user controls that will inherit from my class, BaseControl, which inherits from UserControl. BaseControl is going to include some "stuff" that I'll need. One of them is a string property called ControlValue. I need a way to access that from JavaScript. I've been reading a bit about RegisterExpandoAttribute(), but I'm not sure how to get it to work or where I should put it as the property can change values at anytime. I would prefer to avoid hidden fields.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this depends on many things.  Like what kind of HTML your custom control is creating.

However, the most general way (the way that will work in all cases) is to register some javascript that sets a global value.

Something like this should work:

```
// Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

cs.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "setupglobal", 
  "<script type=text/javascript>var hiImAGlobal = 'sam'; </script>");
```

Remember, I'm not saying this is the *BEST* way, just a way that will work.

Here is the MSDN documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy

Comment: If the user changes the value after I set that, do I just do the same thing again and it'll overwrite that global?

Comment: @Yatrix - I'm not sure.  Maybe you are getting client and server confused?

Comment: You said you're setting a JavaScript global, right? I mentioned in the question the answer can change, so I wanted to know how I could set it again if it's already set. If i'ts JavaScript, it's client - pretty simple, I think.

Comment: The code above creates a global javascript variable called `hiImAGlobal` which can be changed just like any other variable in javascript.  If you reload the page the javascript will get created again by the server and rerun locally and the change will go away.  Does this answer your question?  If not I need a better use case.